# URL в запросах Android Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Всем салам. У меня есть сервер скажем такой адрес к файлу
"https://example.com/index.php".
Делаю простой пост запрос okHttp но с ошибкой вместо протокола https вставляю http может ли изза этого выдать ошибку?

Comment: Попробовал сделать в Postman как вы описали, у меня ошибки не было.

Comment: ошибку может выдать если вместо http вставить https

Comment: @Сергей А наоборот нет?

Comment: @user8978194 без вашего кода ничего не понятно. Может вы вообще используете не тот класс.